# Fit images (both landscape and portrait) into square thumbnail

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I'm really struggling to get images that are both landscape and portrait orientation to fit nicely into a square thumbnail for the purpose of a gallery.

I've tried a variety of CSS tricks but think i need to maybe use Javascript.

Anybody have any idea how i could solve this?

EDIT - the HTML/CSS can be anything, at present it simply prints out images with a class of thumb-square, ie.

```
<img class="thumb_square" src="/images/uploads/pic.jpg"/>
<img class="thumb_square" src="/images/uploads/pic2.jpg"/>
<img class="thumb_square" src="/images/uploads/pic3.jpg"/>
```

Comment: post your html of thumbnail and all

Comment: I've written a web photo library and found the easiest method was to store the thumbnail dimensions in the databse and set the left-margin and top-margin of the <img> based on those dimensions. But you haven't given much info on your implementation so it is difficult to be more specific.

Comment: If you want a mismatched shaped image to always fill into your thumbnail exactly, you have two options:  1) You can scale/stretch/squeeze it to fit or 2) You can scale it proportionally without distortion and clip the longer edge that doesn't quite fit.  Which do you want?

Comment: Ideally, would like to scale it without distortion, i'm not fussed about cropping parts of the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution (tested): Display each thumbnail in a `div`. Show the thumbnail using the css `background` property, and `center` with `no-repeat`. You must specify the `width` and `height` of the containing `div`. Set the width and height to the maximum width/height of all your thumbnails. I.e. if your thumbnails are 150px*200px and 200px*150px, set all divs to be 200px*200px. The thumbnails will then be centered within a 200px*200px box, regardless if they are in portrait or landscape "mode".

Example:

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px;
   background: url('/images/uploads/pic.jpg') no-repeat center;
   border:1px solid red;">
</div>

<div style="width:200px; height:200px;
   background: url('/images/uploads/pic2.jpg') no-repeat center;
   border:1px solid red;">
</div>

<div style="width:200px; height:200px;
   background: url('/images/uploads/pic3.jpg') no-repeat center;
   border:1px solid red;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but as the images are about 600px wide, it's only showing a very small part of them, is there a way to size the background image?

Comment: @CarlBembridge You should really resize the images with a photo editor (Photoshop, ImageMagick or similar) to thumbnail-size (100-300px maybe), before using the images as thumbnails. Otherwise, it will take time loading your page with all these big images...

Comment: They want to keep the images high resolution for the purpose of high DPI displays like the ipad/macbook pro. That was the main reason i wasn't resizing on upload.

So I think this method will work perfect if we resize the images on upload, i think to make the images clickable i'll need to stick a transparent png or something in there as a link to the full image, but this seems the best way to get them all the correct scale. Thanks very much :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think this is exactly what you need:
No matter how big the images are, you will see the whole height (if landscape), or width (if portrait);

jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ECRc4/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="thumb" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/250x500')"></div>
<br/>
<div class="thumb" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/500x200')"></div>
<br/>
<div class="thumb" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100x200')"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumb{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:center;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Nahn, it's a great solution. Because Background-size:Cover is not supported by older browsers (and this client was using older version of Internet Explorer), it wouldn't quite of fit this problem. However, it's a great technique to use going forward :-)